# How to 'restart' angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS app I have a service that is based on WebSocket. If the WebSocket connection breaks, I want to fully 'restart' the application (go to default page from $route, recreate the service etc.). Is that achievable? This is how I started, but from that point I have no idea how to proceed:

Module:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('mainModule', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
            when('/home', {

                templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
                controller: 'appController'
            }).
            when('/register', {

                templateUrl: 'partials/register.html',
                controller: 'appController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home'
            });
        }]);
}());
```

Service:

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('mainModule');

    app.service('$wsService', ['$q', '$window', function ($q, $window) {

        $window.console.log("WebSocket SERVICE: started");

        var self = this;
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:9090");
        this.isConnected = function (m) {};

        ws.onopen = function () {
            $window.console.log("WebSocket SERVICE: connected");
            self.isConnected(true);
        };

        ws.onmessage = function (m) {
            //do whatever I want to do
        };

        ws.onerror = function () {
            $window.console.log("WebSocket SERVICE: disconnected");
            self.isConnected(false);
        };

    }]);
}());
```

Controller:

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('mainModule');

    app.controller('appController', ['$route', '$scope', '$wsService', function ($route, $scope, $wsService) {

        $wsService.isConnected = function (m) {
            //restart logic
        };
    }]);
}());
```

So as my 'restart logic' I tried "$route.reload();" but as you already know it doesn't do what I need. Eventually I will have a warning message pop up (bootstrap modal) informing the user that the connection has been lost, and on a button click in that modal it will reload the app and go to /home. I am not asking how to do that popup etc as this is already done. As for now however, I need to figure out just the logic for total reload of the app. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure there are far better answers to come for this, but I actually JUST ran into this issue with `ui-router` where the suggested resolution didn't work properly for me (it only reloaded the views controller) so I had to resort to pure javascript, first checking `$location.$$absUrl`, if on the "start page" I just do a `location.reload()`, else I just `window.location = '/home'`.

Comment: Why reload the entire app? Wouldn't reconnecting be enough?

Comment: I have some state saved in the application, and as well as reconnect I want to reset that state. Instead of changing 20 scope variables to the default values, I can restart the entire app. I know it is not the best way, but will have to do for now.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To answer my own question, achieved with a trial and error:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $location.path('/home');
    $window.location.reload();
});
```

This will go to /home (default) and reload everything, thus creating new service, module, controllers etc. If there is a better way of doing it (if I change default path to /blah in my module, this won't pick it up and thus I will have to edit this code too), let me know :)

Comment: Does anyone have a different solution to this? Above code works, but you see the app switch states before the page reloads...sort of a bad UX

Comment: this will work if you do not store any data in cookies, localStorage or sessionStorage, if you use any of these you will need to reset values to their defaults

Answer (score 8):

I achieved the same thing doing:

```
$window.location.href = '/home';
```

Comment: This one worked fine for me to initiate a logout by removing the login cookie first and reload app afterwards. Slightly changed the path to make it work:  
`$cookies.remove('COOKIENAME', {path: "/"});  
$window.location.href = './#!/home';`

Answer (score 2):

A little tweak I did to your answer that helped a lot with the UI refreshing. Is to do the path change inside the reload success callback:

`$window.location.reload().then(
            function success(){
              $location.path('/home');
            },
            function error(error) {}
          );`

Most of the time it gives a very smooth transition, presuming you are restarting while redirecting to a different page.